# Confirming Child Abuse

Tags: united-states, child-abuse

### Confirming Child Abuse

What is the minimum amount of evidence needed to legally verify child abuse (or neglect) is occurring, what parties "officially" confirm this, and is it only "officially" confirmed and on record if it goes to court?

- I'm interested in knowing if there are **federal laws** that apply to everyone in the United States about this, or if these are [Florida] per **state laws**?
- I'm interested in knowing when it's *most likely* for the courts to get involved in a reported instance to be investigated.
- I'm also interested in knowing if it is always left up to a single case worker's discretion (ever more than one just in case) per incident to confirm and report child abuse it higher authority.
- It'd be helpful to know (if applicable) at what level of abuse typically requires parents to prove themselves fit to care for a child, take parenting classes, attend anger management, etc. if there is such a grading scale for the level of confirmed abuse.

Comment: I've never heard of "*confirmed* child abuse" as a legal term. What are you referencing?

Comment: read Fla case law - that is the best teacher of criteria of a state you can get - read, rest, reflect best place to get knowledge and understanding usually far better than general view -  see what the courts say you can count on those words, views - it is the horse's mouth